# Syntax error in FROM clause

Tags: select, ms-access

Estoy intentando sumar los valores que retornan estas dos consultas en *`MS Access`*, y recibo el error

> "Syntax error in FROM clause"

Ya he intentado de muchas maneras lograr la suma de estas dos consultas, alguien podría decirme en que me estoy equivocando. Gracias

```
SELECT SUM(SUMA) AS ahorro, generador  FROM (SELECT sum(ahorro) as SUMA, 
generador from kaizen where ESTATUS= 'Cerrado' AND YEAR(fechaValidacion) 
= '2018' and tipoAhorro= 'Hard Perimetral'  GROUP BY generador) + SELECT 
sum(ahorro1) as SUMA,generador from kaizen where ESTATUS= 'Cerrado' AND 
YEAR(fechaValidacion) = '2018' and tipoAhorro1= 'Hard Perimetral' and 
generador GROUP BY generador
```

Comment: Falta un espacio después de `FROM`. Además me parece que la consulta se podría simplificar

Comment: De que forma? Ya he corregido el espacio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error sintáctico está con el signo "+" de la tercera línea

```
GROUP BY generador) + SELECT
```

Tienes dos maneras de hacer eso:

La primera es asegurarte de solo devolver un único campo por cada SELECT, y agrupar usando parentesis las dos subconsultas

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(ahorro1) FROM ...) + (SELECT SUM(ahorro2) FROM ...) AS SUMA
```

La segunda es utilizando el operador UNION en lugar del signo +. (Ver https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-1f772ec0-cc73-474d-ab10-ad0a75541c6e)

Quedaría algo como:

```
SELECT SUM(SUMA), Generador
FROM 
(
    SELECT sum(ahorro) as SUMA, generador from kaizen ...
    UNION
    SELECT sum(ahorro) as SUMA, generador from kaizen ...
) GROUP BY generador
```

Un consejo para detectar los errores de sintaxis es pasar tu consulta en validadores de este estilo.
https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/

Espero que te sirva la respuesta,
Saludos

Comment: Me funciono la segunda, tomare el consejo gracias!!